# Why is Java calling my long variable an int?

Tags: java, types, for-loop

I'm running this [timer example](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-measure-elapsed-execution-time.html), and I changed `i` from int to float, to test my machines potential :-) :

```
    //measuring elapsed time using System.nanoTime
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for(long i=0;  i< 9100080000; i++){
        Object obj = new Object();
    }
    long elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```

But java complains that:

```
1 error found:
File: C:\Users\Adel\Code\Javas\MeasureTimeExampleJava.java  [line: 16]
Error: integer number too large: 9100080000
```

It's saying "integer", meaning a long integer? But wouldn't long fit 9,100,080,000 into it? 2^63 is 9223372036854775808 .  Any tips appreciated thanks!

Comment: int is 32-bit data type whereas long is 64-bit data type.

Comment: Yay! it works now! You guys rock!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's not the *variable* which is an `int` - it's the *literal* that you're comparing it with. You just need:

```
i < 9100080000L
```

The compiler doesn't use "what you're doing with the literal" as part of the process of determining the *type* of the literal, nor does it change the type of the literal based on the value (unlike C#, where `9100080000` would be *implicitly* typed as `long` because it's too big for an `int`).

From the [JLS section 3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).
>
> ...
>
> The largest decimal literal of type int is 2147483648 (2<sup>31</sup>).
>
> All decimal literals from 0 to 2147483647 may appear anywhere an int literal may appear.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a decimal literal of type int is larger than 2147483648 (2<sup>31</sup>), or if the decimal literal 2147483648 appears anywhere other than as the operand of the unary minus operator (§15.15.4).

Note that while both `L` and `l` work, I'd always recommend using `L` instead for clarity - otherwise it can look very much like a `1` depending on your font.

Answer (score 3):

`9100080000` is a regular integer constant, and it's out of range. To make it a *long* integer constant, so it will be in range, you can append `L` or `l`:

```
    for(long i=0;  i< 9100080000L; i++){
```

Answer (score 1):

add "l" to your number. the default number in java is integer.
 for(long i=0;  i< 9100800000l; i++){
        Object obj = new Object();
    }

Comment: While `l` will work, it's a *much* better idea to use `L`, as that's more easily distinguishable from `1`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set 9100080000 as a long.

Example:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 9100080000L; i++)
{
  // do something - note the 9100080000L
}
```